# Make exact clone of table row

Tags: jquery

I want to use jquery to make an exact copy of the first row of a table. I found a very helpful bit of jquery here in another question (apologies to author, I can't find it again) and have modified his fiddle.

[fiddle showing column cloned](http://jsfiddle.net/HwzQg/782/)

I need to clone formatting too - so that:

```
<tr style="font-weight:bold">Fred</tr>
```

the fact the text is bold is cloned too. In the fiddle I have posted, the bold formatting is not copied. How can I include that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the style is on the `<tr>` itself , clone the whole row ... then manipulate the clone

```
$("#sourceT tr").each(function () {
    // make clone of row
    var $clone = $(this).clone();
    // remove all but first cell in clone
    $clone.children(':gt(0)').remove();
    //append clone
    $target.append($clone)
});
```

A one liner approach  would be

```
$(this).clone().children(':gt(0)').remove().end().appendTo($target);
// OR
$target.append( $(this).clone().children(':gt(0)').remove().end() );
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hqss4sL5/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there a way to make each row in the copied column exactly the same height as the original? I am trying to make a clone of a huge and complex table - just the first column - so I can keep it still when the table is scrolled horizontally. Some of the cells in the original table - in columns to the right of the first column - are much higher - but my cloned column is getting heights suitable for the (much less) content.

Comment: get height of each row and apply to clone using `height()`

Answer (score 0):

The text is not coming through as bold on the clone is because the style is set on the `tr` element, yet you create a new one of those and copy only the `td` elements. If you want to clone the entire thing, you can simply clone the element referenced in `this` and append it to the other table:

```
var $target = $("#targetT");
$("#sourceT tr").each(function () {
    $(this).clone().appendTo($target);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HwzQg/784/)

Or shorter still:

```
$('#sourceT tr').clone().appendTo('#targetT');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $target = $("#targetT");
$("#sourceT tr:first").clone().appendTo($target);
```

This will clone the first row into target.
[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5v1b8t7u/)